How to search and replace for more than one possible term in Notepad++?
I have the following text in the document and I want to search and replace all instances of Foo and Bar
Foo spot Bar see
Tar bum top Foo
Ipsum gum Bar stop

Using one line in find/replace I'd like the result to be:
 spot  see
Tar bum top 
Ipsum gum  stop

I think what I need is some kind of OR expression for the search field and replace Foo or Bar with nothing. But I don't know how to do this.

I commend your attention to regular expressions, which Notepad++ supports for Search/Replace.

This is pretty simple. You go to Replace menu (Ctrl+H) and in "Find what" enter
Foo|Bar

Leave "Replace with" empty and select "Regular expressions"

And then click "Replace all"
